# How to create a curved or blended shadow in Adobe Fireworks CS5?

Tags: adobe-fireworks

I would like to create a sexy-trending curved or blended shadow **using Adobe Fireworks CS5**.

How can I do that? I would like to achieve a shadow like the following sample:

[image: Curved or blended shadow sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your shadow then use the oval marque tool to create a very wide oval and delete the extra to create a curved shadow. I don't have fireworks, but I will show you in photoshop.

[image: Create your rectangle and place a black duplicate beneath it]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great! Btw which version of Adobe Fireworks are you using?

Comment: Like I said, I don't have fireworks, I just used photoshop, I know that adobe fireworks has similar tools though.